# Unit test RxJava with timeout not subscribe

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I have Unit test function RxJava with timeout but it doesn't subscribe for unit test.
Function on viewModel

```
fun loadData() {
    loadDataUseCase.loadData(true)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .timeout(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, schedulers)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnSubscribe {
            onShowLoading.value = true
            onShowError.value = false
            onShowContent.value = false
        }.subscribe(
            {
                onConnected.value = true
                onShowContent.value = true
                onShowError.value = false
                onShowLoading.value = false
            },
            {
                onShowError.value = true
                onShowLoading.value = false
                onShowContent.value = false
            }
        )
        .addTo(compositeDisposable)
}
```

Function on unit test

```
@Test
fun `Load data is success`() {
    // given
    whenever(loadDataUseCase.loadData(true)).thenReturn(Observable.just(true))

    // when
    viewModel.loadData()

    // then
    viewModel.onShowError().test().assertValue(false).awaitNextValue().assertValue(false)
}
```

I try to debug this function but it doesn't invoke subscribe

Comment: Why are you trying to unit test RxJava?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused, what is onShowError() does it return a LiveData?

If I run the same code the test doesn't even finish (well I use only io dispatchers and postValue), for you it might be finished before the subscription even happens:

Since you rely on `Schedulers.io()` it is possible that your whole Subscription is finished before you get to even test your LiveData.

An other option is that your LiveData already has a false value: `.assertValue(false)`. then the next `.doOnSubscribe` setting already triggers `.awaitNextValue()` and your whole test finishes, before the subscription can even be called.

Your tests should be fixed and not dependent on timing. Or if it is unavoidable then you have to synchronize your test somehow, an example of this is here:

```
@Timeout(1, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Test
fun `Load data is success`() {
    // given
    whenever(loadDataUseCase.loadData(true)).thenReturn(Observable.just(true)
        
    val testObserver = liveData.test()
    testObserver.assertNoValue() // assert in correct state before actions
    
    // when
    loadData(liveData, mock)
    
    //then
    testObserver.awaitValueHistorySize(2)
        .assertValueHistory(false, false)
}

fun <T> TestObserver<T>.awaitValueHistorySize(count: Int, delay: Long = 10): TestObserver<T> {
    awaitValue()
    while (valueHistory().size < count) {
        // we need to recheck and don't block, the value we are trying to wait might already arrived between the while condition and the awaitNextValue in the next line, so we use some delay instead.
        awaitNextValue(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
    return this
}
```